# Rails form used in different partial, or how to reuse method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a ContactsController that looks like:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
 def create
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  if captcha?
   ContactMailer.potential_lead(@contact).deliver if @contact.save
  else
   @contact.errors.add(:base, 'Verify your humanity')
  end
  respond_with @contact
 end

 def thanks
  @contact = 'success'
  render file: '/layouts/contact'
 end

 private

 def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :message, :interest, :email, :phone)
 end
end
```

There are no issues with the ContactsController, views, mailers, etc. All works fine. However I need to add a standalone page and I'm planning on using the ContactsController to handle the form. So I created a new view in Layouts titled widget.

The idea being that when someone fills out the contact form on the widget page there's a hidden field that handles the interest and just uses the contact mailer, etc.

However I'm running into some issues. On my view I have:

```
=content_for :body do
 .container
  .row
   .col
    =render partial: '/shared/widget_form'
```

Then in my partial:

```
=tb_form_for @contact, remote: true, data: {errors: :inline, success: thanks_path } do |f|
 .row
  .col
   = tb_form_errors(f.object, :base)
 .row
  .col
   =f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Name', required: true
```

Then I updated my routes to have

```
resources :contacts, only: [:create]
match 'widget' -> 'contacts#create', via: :post
```

However I end up with

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

I thought maybe it's an issue with doing post, although I want to post to the Contacts > Create, but I changed that to get and end up with:

> param is missing or the value is empty: contact

So I thought I'm probably using match wrong so I'll just do:

```
get 'widget', to: 'contacts#create', as: :widget
```

Then I updated my form to have:

```
=tb_form_for @contact, url: widget_path, remote: true, data: {errors: :inline, success: thanks_path}
```

And I'm still getting

> param is missing or the value is empty: contact

What am I missing? I'd just like to reuse the method on a different page.

EDIT:
If I use:

```
=tb_form_for Contact.new
```

It works....but this feels like a cheat. Any way around this?

Comment: You can try to replace @contact with Contact.new

Comment: It's clear that post request goes to contacts#create but make sure the action renders your form has access to @contact variable.

Answer (score 0):

How does rails render forms?

In short:

1. For example user sends a get request to an `contacts#index`
2. Inside #index action you something like `@contact = Contact.new`
3. By default index.haml view will be rendered for #index action if another view is not specified.
4. In this case index.haml view will be able to access @contact variable.

In your case there is method `= content_for :body do` that renders `partial: '/shared/widget_form'`

I believe there is `yield :body` somewhere in another view or layout.

So to make it work you need to initialize `@contact` variable in any controller that may render view/layout with `yield :body`